# How do I configure a Ruby Mechanize agent to work through the Charles web proxy?

Tags: ruby, proxy, mechanize, charles-proxy

I'm writing an "automatically fill in the forms" app using Ruby / Mechanize.  It almost works.

I can use the wonderful [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) web proxy to see the exchange between the server and my Firefox browser.  Now I want to use Charles to see the exchange between the server and my app.

Charles proxies on port 8888.  Assume that the server is at https://my.host.com.  One thing that does NOT work is:

```
@agent ||= Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.set_proxy("my.host.com", 8888)
end
```

This results in a `Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error`:

```
...lib/net/http/persistent.rb:579:in `rescue in connection_for': connection refused: my.host.com:8888 (Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error)
```

So either I'm giving the wrong host argument to `agent.set_proxy(host, ...)`, or I haven't configured Charles properly.  (FWIW, I used to be able to do this, but both Mechanize and Charles have matured several generations since those halcyon days...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A web proxy is not normally defined by *just* a port, but is usually a full host name. Charles is very likely installed on localhost.  Therefore the following adjustment may work for you:

```
@agent ||= Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.set_proxy("localhost", 8888)
end
```

Comment: For the record the `tap` is unnecessary, Mechanize.new yields itself to the block.

Comment: Thanks -- I should have realized that localhost was the right thing.  It almost works -- now all I have to do is get my `certificate verify failed` errors taken care of.  Different problem...

Comment: @pguardiario: thanks for the tip.  edited the OP (and my source code) accordingly.